# How can I copy String or str

Tags: string, copy, rust, lifetime

I have the following code:

```rust
let mut dirs = vec![String::from(".")];
// This one doesn't work too:
//let mut dirs = vec!["."];

while dirs.len() > 0 {
    let paths = fs::read_dir(dirs.pop().unwrap()).unwrap();
    for path in paths {            
        if path.unwrap().metadata().unwrap().is_dir() {
            dirs.push(String::from(path.unwrap().path().to_str().unwrap()).clone())
            // This one doesn't work too:
            //dirs.push(path.unwrap().path().to_str().unwrap())
        }
    }
}
```

It always gives a compilation error: `use of moved value: 'path' [E0382]`.

I tried different ways and still cannot understand how can I copy a string `path.to_str()` so it can survive longer than `path` variable. Looks like both `String` and `str` don't support `Copy` trait. 
So the main question is how to make the code above work?

I need to make a copy of a string somehow. In C I would use `memcpy` or `strcpy` for that task. Are there any similar functions in Rust?

Comment: You seem to have solved the issue with getting a borrowed `&str` to an owned `String` object yourself. `String::from` works just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `unwrap()` will move your `path` object. The easiest way is to move it once in the beginning of the loop by saying

```
let path = path.unwrap();
```

and then working with the unwrapped path object:

```
let mut dirs = vec![String::from(".")];

while dirs.len() > 0 {
    let paths = fs::read_dir(dirs.pop().unwrap()).unwrap();
    for path in paths {
        let path = path.unwrap();
        if path.metadata().unwrap().is_dir() {
            dirs.push(String::from(path.path().to_str().unwrap()))
        }
    }
}
```